# jar file not properly finding the files

Tags: java, file, text, jar, executable-jar

I have spent the past 3 nights going crazy trying to find an answer to this.
So I have a java program and I want it to be in a jar format and I want it to be able to read in text and image files.
I got the image files working fine using the `this.getClass.getResource("")` method, however I can not get the program to properly access the text files within the .jar, When I extract the jar, the text files are there so I know It is not a simple mistake of the text files not being within the jar

This is what I tried using, but it didn't work(It works without a jar, but now within a jar)

```
URL lurl = this.getClass().getResource("list.txt");
BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lurl.getFile()));
```

Fixes?

Comment: What does you error stacktrace look like you have to treat the resource as an InputStream, not just as another file you can open using FileReader.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you talking about this method?
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename");

Comment: yes, use getResourceAsStream

Comment: but FileReader does not have a constructor for an inputstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class is

```
my.package.MyClass
```

The method will read the file from directory `/my/package` from JAR.

You can open the resource via:

```
BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("list.txt")));
```

Comment: Ok wow thank you very much, I got that to work now, but my only problem now, is that I can't apply this code to other parts in my program because it only brings it in as an inputstream, how would I deal with output streams?
BufferedWriter out2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("list.txt"));
out2.write(a1.getText());
out2.close();

Comment: You can't write to jar that way. You could try open it as zip, but trying to modify the jar that was loaded by ClassLoader could lead to unpredictable behaviour (assuming that operating system will allow such operation).